# Position of the Tags and Content of Pages removing the CSS Style

Tags: seo, css

Hi there guys at Pro Webmasters!

Have a little question (Maybe for a newbie) ... So here it goes:
When I choose to see a mobile page of my website with the "Web developer" Plug of Chrome I notice that the H1 Title of the Page it's situated very very deep under the page.

So.. the thing is that it would be good for SEO to put it more likely on the top of the Page?
Is that true?
Any helps of thoughts?

Here is a caption of the page with and  without CSS style:

[image]

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: I'd say this is just fine. Your website, not Googles. You could try to add it earlier in the DOM (htmlstructure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the position of the h1 element important (at least I do) then what actually matters is its position within the code of your page. Google certainly won't "see" what the *Web developer Plug-In for Chrome* presents to you. Instead what does count is the position in relation to the other page elements such as h2 etc.

I do actually cosider the hierarchy of h-elements improtant – which means that h1 comes before h2 (since a.s.a.i.k. that's how the headline tags are meant to be used) but this does not mean, that h1 should be the ***very*** first element on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No :)

Check out this link: http://moz.com/search-ranking-factors

In short: Today the importance of h1 is not as great as in the past, what counts is the voice of the community than the number of links to a page, or how it was built.

Of course, appearance and proper functioning of the hand to give you additional votes (pluses and likes), also counts semantic correctness. It should remember to use multiple headers various degrees (the higher the less).

One very important thing: do not try to cheat Google :)

http://www.quora.com/Does-using-multiple-h1-tags-on-a-page-affect-search-engine-rankings

For some more info check this link:
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/2014-important-h1-tag-seo/106613/